# Как написать форму на ASP.NET MVC2 и использовать в ней GWT?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gwt

Есть форма которая написана на ASP.NET MVC2, она передает параметры на контроллер. Но на форме есть много моментов для связи с контроллером через AJAX. 
Есть вариант написать эту часть через GWT (потому как знаю технологию хорошо и писать на ней мне проще). Весь вопрос в том - как это сделать крассиво? И вообще может кто поделиться мнением на этот счет?

Answer (score 1):

Так в чём конкретно сложность? Почему не использовать стандартный [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html)?

Comment: Сложности никакой, сам хотел так сделать. Просто как думаете насколько стоит смешивать две технологии? Какие есть плюсы и где тут минусы?

Comment: Минус в смешении технологий. Это само по себе минус :)

Comment: В том смысле, что если фронтэнд делаете на GWT, то делайте его по возможности на нём целиком